# no mixin named flexdisplay

Tags: sass, mixins, scss-mixins

This is my _mixins.scss file:

```
@mixin flexdisplay($flex_direction:column, $justify:center) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: $justify;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: $flex_direction;
}
```

And this is my _header.scss file:

```
.header {
    @include flexdisplay("column", "space-between");
    padding: 20px;
}
```

The error message says that there is no mixin named flexdisplay

Comment: Have you imported _mixins.scss file into _header.scss file?

Comment: @Sunil ah thanks, i forgot about that

Comment: For those who had imported the scss file properly and still faced the issue. Double check the import order of the scss files.

Make sure the imports occur above the code where to try to access the mixin.

Answer (score 0):

You have most probably forgot to add import following resources

```
@import 'mixins';
@import 'variables';
```